# Are there any compounds with pentagonal pyramidal molecular geometry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure

As a high school student, I am curious whether there are any compounds with [pentagonal pyramidal molecular geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_pyramidal_molecular_geometry). I know that most compounds having hexacoordinated central atom and having $\sigma = 6$ and $\mathrm{lp} = 1$ $(\ce{XeF6},$ $\ce{IF6-})$ have either capped octahedral or distorted octahedral shape, or they have perfect octahedral shape $(\ce{ICl6-},$ $\ce{SeF6^2-}),$ where the lone pair goes to the stereochemically inactive orbital.

Are there any compounds hexacoordinated central atom and $\sigma = 6$ and $\mathrm{lp} = 1$ which have pentagonal pyramidal geometry?

Comment: Tellurium (https://doi.org/10.1107/s0108270195005154; https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270195004902; https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270195004914; https://doi.org/10.1107/10.1021/ja00228a026; https://doi.org/10.3891/acta.chem.scand.44-0139; https://doi.org/10.1107/S010827019600234X; https://doi.org/10.1016/j.poly.2007.11.007; https://doi.org/10.1107/10.3891/acta.chem.scand.49-0834) and bismuth (https://doi.org/10.1039/c1dt11207d; https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-328X(03)00435-2; https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201509629) have quite several examples.

Comment: @andselisk You should convert that into an answer.